# JAVA - IllegalStateException: unmanaged resource freed from pool D3D Vram Pool

Tags: java, javafx, illegalstateexception

My Javafx application throws many illegalStateException which i have not yet been able to trace the trigger in the source.

can anyone please guide me to what can cause this and where should i be looking to find the reason. its hard for me to show some code here since i dont know what's causing it.

any help will be appreciated.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unmanaged resource freed from pool D3D Vram Pool
at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseResourcePool.resourceFreed(BaseResourcePool.java:463)
at com.sun.prism.impl.ManagedResource.dispose(ManagedResource.java:127)
at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseTexture.dispose(BaseTexture.java:297)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.prism.ps.PPSDrawable.flush(PPSDrawable.java:69)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.ImagePool.dispose(ImagePool.java:267)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.impl.Renderer.getRenderer(Renderer.java:367)
at com.sun.scenario.effect.ImageData.validate(ImageData.java:216)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.CacheFilter.render(CacheFilter.java:522)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderCached(NGNode.java:2372)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2058)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1959)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:576)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2067)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1959)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:576)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2067)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1959)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:576)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2067)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1959)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:576)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2067)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1959)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:576)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2067)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1959)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:474)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:327)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
```

Comment: Can you post some code that could be related to this trace? Just only with that is difficult to answer.

Comment: that is the problem that i dont know what could be related to this issue :( and i cant post the whole code here, its too much.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this issue, and for me it corresponded with a graphics driver crash.  So far, I've only seen it happen on a laptop where I know the GPU is failing (semi-frequently resulting in frozen displays or blue screens of death with an nVIDIA GPU driver cited as the cause).

I suspect what is happening is that due to a graphics hardware issue, the GPU driver is freeing some memory that the JVM has reserved, causing this exception.

In my most recent stack trace, the screen froze momentarily, the system recovered from the GPU driver crash, and  when I looked at my logs right afterwards, this error showed up three times.  I would recommend testing on another machine, and if you cannot reproduce the problem elsewhere, you may similarly have GPU hardware or driver issues resulting in this exception.